# Database Connection Pooling (w/ Java)

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

I would like to know your thoughts on whether this type of methodology could be practically implemented. I am very knew to database pooling, so forgive me for any misunderstandings. I have multiple classes calling a dbData class (which connects to a database and has helper functions, like frequently uses gets and updates and etc). I need to keep all the get and update functions in dbData class, but keep a pool of active connections I can re-use. Which means I will instantiate the dbData class multiple times, each time checking whether an appropriate connection exists, if not, create a new one and put it into the pool.

My question is this how and where you would store this pool. I could perhaps accomplish this if dbData would not be instantiated more than once and keeps one persistent pool object. But in my case, I have multiple dbData instances which should all connect to a single pool. I thought about serializing the pool object, but this seems ridiculous. Is this possible (what is shown in the pic)? It seems I am having trouble with the object-oriented part of this design.

The applications uses multithreading with Class1 and Class2.

I would not like to use any external libraries if possible.

[image: db pool img]

Comment: Are you running this in a container environment (e.g. on Tomcat, JBoss, ..) or as a standalone Java application?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid existing libraries/methodologies? This is an essentially solved problem, through libraries or containers. If you're dead-set on reinventing it, take a look at [commons-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/), built on [commons-pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/), for ideas on how to re-implement it :/

Comment: Standalone Java app. I would not like to use existing libraries to keep it simple. I read some IBM documentation on Java DBCP and it  essentially looks like just a HashSet with connections. I don't think I need to go all out and get a huge library.

Comment: It seems I forgot about static variables. I'll just make this pool static and keep querying it for connections even though there are multiple instances of dbData.

Comment: Keeping it simple IS using those other libraries, not writing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a standalone app, then I would create a seperate service with a static collection that keeps the connection and does all the handling of those. Then the dbData class can call the static method to get a connection. The service then itself takes care of creating new connections if required. If your dbData instances are running in parallel you have to think about synchronized access (if required).

Comment: Realized it the same time you did - a static synchronized pool. I just find it a waste to use a 7MB library for a thing you can implement yourself with some thinking. Thanks.

Comment: It is probably a waste, but on the other side reinventing the wheel? :-) Of course it makes fun, but could lead to errors which others already fought.

Comment: You're right. There is an also an issue with licensing due to the fact this will used for commericial purposes.

Comment: You would have no issues with the commons-dbcp license.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the singleton design pattern?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/singletons/